# Unsuitable fit for tanh function in python

Tags: python

I am trying to fit a tanh function for the dataset shown below. The code has always worked, but there seem to be problems with this dataset. The displayed fit does not fit the data points at all.

I have already tried a few things but have not been able to find a solution.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
import numpy as np

xdata = [26, -30, -60, 80, 110, 60, 40]
ydata = [53, 12.6, 15.8, 100, 102.1, 90.4, 70.2]

def tanh(x, a, b, c, d ):
    return a * np.tanh( b * x + c ) + d

p0 = [max(ydata), np.median(xdata),1,min(ydata)]
popt, pcov = curve_fit(tanh, xdata, ydata, p0, method='dogbox')

xModel = np.linspace(min(xdata), max(xdata))
yModel = tanh(xModel, *popt)

def Plot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(16,9))
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.plot(xdata, ydata,  'D', label="data")
    ax.plot(xModel, yModel, label="fit")
    ax.legend()
    plt.show()

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600

Plot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

[image: Tanh fit]

How can I improve the fitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide suitable starting parameters, for example, in the `curve_fit` call, use:

```
p0=(100, 0.01, 1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. The p0 parameters work very well. Is there a method to determine the p0 parameters? How did you choose the parameters?

Comment: @Gopala You can estimate some parameters from the data and knowing the tanh function. For example, the data extends from roughly 20 to 100, and tanh from -1 to 1, so a factor of 100 for the amplitude. And tanh spans most of its change between -2 and 2, while your data shows -25 to 75, so another factor 100 for b, but this time the inverse: 1/100.